# Dart: Remove from Iterable until criteria is met

Tags: flutter, dart, iterable

I am having an `Iterable<MyClass>` where `MyClass` has an attribute `data`. Now I want to remove elements from my Iterable starting from the last added item. I want to remove them until the sum of all characters in all `data` attributes that are still in the Iterable are below some threshold.

Of course I could just iterate over the list, remove the last, then check, remove next etc. With a simple loop and if-statement. I just wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this in dart? Using some builtin function?

Thanks!

Comment: it seems like you want to build a list that is always under the total sum, so for each item, if the current list plus the item is still good, add it, and repeat.  Stop when it won't fit.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to know what approach you're using now

But if I had a similar problem
I would do it this way:

class MyClass {
String data;

```
  MyClass(this.data);
}

void main() {
  Iterable<MyClass> myIterable = [
    MyClass("abc"),
    MyClass("def"),
    MyClass("ghi"),
    MyClass("jkl"),
  ];

  int threshold = 10; // Your threshold value

  // Calculate the sum of characters in all data attributes
  int sum = myIterable.map((myClass) => myClass.data.length).fold(0, (prev, length) => prev + length);

  // Remove elements from the end until the sum is below the threshold
  List<MyClass> remaining = myIterable.toList().reversed.takeWhile((myClass) {
    sum -= myClass.data.length;
    return sum >= threshold;
  }).toList();

  print(remaining); // Remaining elements after removal
}
```

Comment: I just did `int sum = 0;` now and `sum += ...` and return `sum <= threshold`